# SQL to find common traits among all users

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve just the common traits from all the users.

```
  User(u)Trait(t)
  u1      t1
  u1      t2
  u1      t3
  u2      t2
  u2      t3
  u2      t4
  u3      t2
  u3      t3
  u3      t4
```

[image: example dataset]

I'm trying to join the table to itself but not getting the desired output.

I expect the output of the above to be t2 and t3 and these are the only traits that are present in all the 3 users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select ut.trait
from usertraits ut
group by ut.trait
having count(*) = (select count(distinct ut2.user) from usertraits ut2);
```